# How can I kill a child_process spwaned by node.js/electron correctly in windows?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, electron

I am using Electron, Python and Flask to develop an app in Windows.

I use

```
require('child_process').spawn('python', [_script,port])
```

to start a child_process, but I cannot kill this child_process correctly.

When the electron app was closed, there was still a process called 'python' working in the background.

I tried almost every way, for instance p.kill(), or using taskkill.

Here is the python code:

```py
from flask import Flask
import logiccode as mine

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
   return mine.HelloWorld()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

```
//create
pyProc = require('child_process').spawn('python', [_script,port])
    if (pyProc != null) {
        console.log('child process success\n')
        console.log(pyProc.pid);
    }

//kill

if(process.platform=='win32'){
        require('child_process').spawn('taskkill',['/pid','/f','/t',pyProc.pid]);
    }else{
        pyProc.kill();
        pyProc = null
        pyPort = null
    }
```

If there is some error in the code, please tell me how I can kill this child_process correctly.

Comment: what about if you open task manager tab processes and kill it from there. If you definately need to do it via command-line there are some limitations of default commandline in windows you would need to open the terminal in administrator mode

Comment: it's true that I have to kill this process by windows task manager , i'll try to find out if it's this reason.

Comment: I try to run this in cmd with administrator account,but the python process still alive in the background.lol

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason for the Windows-specific branch there, I assume you added it when `pyProc.kill()` didn't work.

[`kill`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal) defaults to SIGTERM. I'd expect that to work, but if you're seeing it not work, you can use the nuclear option of SIGKILL instead. As it says in [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

So:

```
//kill
pyProc.kill('SIGKILL');
pyProc = null
pyPort = null
```

Comment: I try this way but the problem still exist. there was still a Python process in the background

Comment: @KIndoRua - That suggests to me that you're spawning the process more than once. Only the last process assigned to `pyProc` would be killed. It's bound to be something like that, only debugging will tell... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is not too late but I ran into the same problem, the reason why flask cannot be killed is because debug mode is set to True. Just call app.run() and node will kill flask.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```